# Filter Data frame using selectInput (Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny-server

I'm trying to write a shiny app that will display the frequency of subcomponents based on the selection of a main component (via selectInput). This is the first time I've played around with shiny, so I've been trying to follow various tutorials. However, I can't seem to get the dataset filtering correct when using selectInput. This is the error message I keep running into:

```
Warning in c("A", "A", "B", "B") == list(impl = <environment>, readonly = TRUE,  :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
Warning: Error in eval: object 'SelectComponent' not found
```

My code follows below:

DF looks like:

```
Component    Subcomponent    Freq
 A            Blue            10
 A            Green           15
 B            Red             20 
 B            Yellow          35
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("Components"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  helpText("Create Component graphs"),

  selectInput("SelectComponent", "Choose a component to display",
              choices = c("A", "B"))

),

# Show a plot of the Subcomponents
mainPanel(
 plotOutput("SubcompPlot")
)
)
))
```

server.R

```
Component <- c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B')
Subcomponent <- c('Blue', 'Green', 'Red', 'Yellow')
Freq <- c(10, 15, 20, 25)
ExampleDF<- data.frame(Component, Subcomponent, Freq, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

Server <- function(input, output) {

  output$SubcompPlot <- renderPlot({

    Filtered <- 
      ExampleDF %>%
      filter(Component == input&SelectComponent)

    ggplot(data=Filtered, aes(x = Filtered$Subcomponent, y = Filtered$Freq)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  })
}
```

I've tried other approaches such as replacing the filtering with a line like this:

```
Filtered = reactive(ExampleDF[which(ExampleDF$Component == input$SelectComponent),])
```

but that returns a ggplot error:

```
Warning: Error in : ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class reactive
```

Any advice on how to use the selectInput value to filter the data would be much appreciated! I know I must be missing some basic things, but I just can't figure out.

Thanks

Comment: Your second approach is good, but a reactive is a function, so use `ggplot(data=Filtered(), ...`

Comment: I guess you have a typo while filtering the dataset. You have a `&` instead of a `$`.  `Filtered <- ExampleDF %>% filter(Component == input$SelectComponent)`  works for me

Comment: Aside from a small typo (`input&SelectComponent` should have a $ instead of &), your code works for me. Maybe update the packages and try again?

Comment: Thanks everyone! Fixing the typo + making sure things were updated seemed to do the trick. Clearly I was staring at the code for far too long and missed that silly typo!